# How to use Java's JAR file with Aptana RadRail's JRuby project?

Tags: jruby, radrails

everyone. I am trying to use Aptana RadRail to work on my JRuby project. A good feature of JRuby is, able to use Java library in the world. but I try to find out how to make this happen with Aptana RadRail IDE.

NetBeans is also good IDE, but I like Eclipse-styled. Could you tell me how to make this happen? Do I have to do this via IDE or another solution?

Answer (score 1):

Despite what the linked-to article above says, you can manually set your classpath env variable before invoking jruby.

You can also put jar files in JRUBY_HOME/lib and they are automatically on the classpath.

These and the above mentioned techniques will work regardless of which IDE you use (or even if you use no IDE at all).

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this very good blog entry](http://blogs.oracle.com/coolstuff/entry/using_java_classes_in_jruby)

Basicly you can do

```
require "/some/path/MyStuff.jar"
```

or even

```
require "/some/path/*.jar"
```